# Cannot POST - Cloud 9

Tags: php, html, sql, cloud9-ide

I have a form on cloud 9 and want it to INSERT INTO a sql database I have with cloud 9.  However, every time I click submit, it tells me

```
Cannot POST /user/project/connect.php
```

Is this a feature I'm not allowed to use on a free account or am I just messing up my code?

Comment: Hi, you may have more luck getting an answer to your question on community.c9.io. FWIW I don't really see how that would be related to being non-premium. Maybe it works if you change your workspace application URL to be "public" in the sharing dialog, though?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a VM specific issue, whether you have configured database correctly, your file location.

As per my experience with free-account, there are no issues with database connectivity in C9.